# Tor onion routing process

Tags: onion-routing, tunnel

I am trying to understand the Tor anonymity process. I figure out that Onion routing is the concept which makes it more impressive. So if I am correct list of Onion routers(OR's) are loaded on client and payload is encrypted and encapsulated, layer by layer. So does that mean if we have 2 OR(OR 1 and OR2) then packet is like [[[[payload]OR2 to D]OR1 to OR2]S to OR1]

Am I right? Also, Is it technically correct statement that we have tunneled multiple times according to OR numbers. I mean is tunneling of packet is technically correct or only term encapsulation can be used?

Answer (score 0):

if it's encapsulated it's akin to a VPN, ie encapsulation should be the correct term used. Encryption is commensurate with VPN technologies